# Downloading ZPL code from Zebra printer storage in Dynamics NAV

Tags: .net, printing, zebra-printers, zpl, zpl-ii

I'm connecting to a ZEBRA network printer in Dynamic NAV via TCP/IP and have a few functions that work perfectly good.
One function is reading the integrated flash storage of the printer and returns the stored label templates.

My question is: Is there any way to get the ZPL-code which is behind those labels saved in the printer so I can store it in my table?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get the source code of the label templates by using the ZEBRA Designer, as stated on the Zebra website:

> Programmers can create their labels using the free version and then
>   output the printer language to a file to provide a starting point for
>   programming their label application.